# Can't provide @ in javascript when using razor view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
var regularExpression = 
    /^(?=(.*\d){2})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%]{8,}/;
var valid = regularExpression.test(pwd);
```

The problem is, when I provide this string in javascript, the @ symbol acts as a razor views code nugget.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind! I got the answer by myself; using @@ in javascript rather than @, which symbolizes for razor view.

Comment: Then, choose this as the answer.